# How can I connect two objects for cloth simulation?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

Context:  I am modeling an object that will be simulated as cloth.  I would like to attach two "velco" handles onto the main piece.

Initially, I just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the handles to the main piece.  I then pin the two handles, but when I run the cloth simulation, the main piece detaches and falls away.

How can I get the handles to hold the main piece and drape accordingly?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you better explain what you want?

Comment: The handles should probably be joined with actual geometry, e.g. there should be faces joining the handles and the main cloth.

Comment: Link the mesh's in edit mode, and it will simulate as though they are connected.

Comment: Did you try using the new sewing feature. Try searching Google Blender Developer Sneak Peek #8 for the details.  Or wait for a proper answer from someone here.  You didn't really give any details or provide a blend file so it's going to be hard for people to guess at your setup or what you may be doing wrong.